# How cant I count number of element in antlr listener exit function?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have such grammar:

```
xor_expression
    : or_expression (XOR or_expression)*
    ;
```

How can I count how many `(XOR or_expression)*` repeats is occurred in this rule. This is need to get from stack valid number of arguments. For example for `1 xor 1 xor 1` - I need 3 for `1 xor 1` I need 2, etc.

This give me total children but it is not relevant.

```
public override void ExitXor_expression([NotNull] preprintParser.Xor_expressionContext context)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(context.ChildCount);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you go through all children and count the ones that are of type `or_expressionContext`?

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of `or_expression` children in the rule, use labels:

```
xor_expression
    : expr+=or_expression (XOR expr+=or_expression)*
    ;
```

This will produce, within the `Xor_expressionContext`, a field

```
List<ParseTree> expr;
```

containing the `or_expression` instances actually matched. Obviously, `expr.size()` will then give the requested count.

Answer (score 0):

```
grammar Question;

/* Count xor. */

question
@init {System.out.println("Question last update 1950");}
    :   expr+ EOF
    ;

expr
    :   xor_expression
    ;

xor_expression
    : or_expression ( xors+='xor' or_expression )*
      {System.out.println($text + " : " + $ctx.or_expression().size() + " or_expression with " + $ctx.xors.size() + " XOR" );}
    ;

or_expression
    :   atom
    ;

atom
    :   ID
    |   NUMBER
    ;

ID     : [a-z]+ ;
NUMBER : [0-9]+ ;
WS     : [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
```

Input file t.text :

```
1 xor 1
1 xor 1 xor 1
```

Execution with ANTLr 4.6 :

```
$ grun Question question -tokens -diagnostics t.text
[@0,0:0='1',<NUMBER>,1:0]
[@1,1:1=' ',<WS>,channel=1,1:1]
[@2,2:4='xor',<'xor'>,1:2]
[@3,5:5=' ',<WS>,channel=1,1:5]
[@4,6:6='1',<NUMBER>,1:6]
...
[@16,22:21='<EOF>',<EOF>,3:0]
Question last update 1950
1 xor 1 : 2 or_expression with 1 XOR
1 xor 1 xor 1 : 3 or_expression with 2 XOR
```

These numbers should be accessible from the listener. They belong to the rule context. Extract from Parser :

```
public static class Xor_expressionContext extends ParserRuleContext {
    public Token s1;
    public List<Token> xors = new ArrayList<Token>();
    public List<Or_expressionContext> or_expression() {
        return getRuleContexts(Or_expressionContext.class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I (1) modified your grammar a bit, adding a visitor rule, calling it `XOR`:

```
// file xor.g4
grammar: xor ;
prog : xor_expression+ EOF ;
xor_expression
    : or_expression (XOR or_expression)* NEWLINE          #XOR
    ;
or_expression : 'true' | 'false' ;
XOR : 'XOR' ;
WS  :   [ \t]+ -> skip ; // toss out whitespace
NEWLINE : '\r'? '\n' ;
```

Next, `antlr xor.g4 -visitor` auto-generates a visitor base impl in `xorBaseVisitor.java` which includes a method `visitXOR( xorParser.XORContext ctx )`. (2) I extended that class and reimplemented this method, where I can obtain both kinds of counts - tokens or "real parts" (I don't know what they are called in CS)

```
public Integer visitXOR( xorParser.XORContext ctx ) {
    List<xorParser.Or_expressionContext> mylist = ctx.or_expression();
    System.out.println("visitXOR - #or children = " + mylist.size());
    System.out.println("visitXOR - #getChildCount() = " + ctx.getChildCount());
    for( xorParser.Or_expressionContext x : mylist ) {
            System.out.println( "\t" + x.getText() );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The key to this lies in `xorParser.java` which generates a rule context class with a method to return a list of `or_expression`s

```
public static class XORContext extends Xor_expressionContext {
    public List<Or_expressionContext> or_expression() {
        return getRuleContexts(Or_expressionContext.class);
    }
...
```

Here is a sample run

```
$ antlr4 -visitor -no-listener xor.g4  && javac -g XorTest.java *xor*java
Note: XorTest.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
$ java XorTest
true
true XOR false XOR true
^D
visitXOR - #or children = 1
visitXOR - #getChildCount() = 2
        true
visitXOR - #or children = 3
visitXOR - #getChildCount() = 6
        true
        false
        true
$
```

HTH